# How to avoid crystalreport ask database authentication when i change a page

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Hello friends I have a question, I have my report (.rpt) It shows good but when I press the button to see the folloging page It ask me for the parameter and the database authentication, this is my code:

```
cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
try
{
    cryRpt.Load((Application.StartupPath + "\\rpExclu.rpt").Replace("\\bin\\Debug", ""));
    cryRpt.SetParameterValue("@IDA", id);
    cryRpt.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "password$$$");
    crvReportes.ReportSource = cryRpt;
    crvReportes.Refresh();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    crvReportes.Refresh();
    XtraMessageBox.Show("" + ex.Message.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
finally
{
    cryRpt.Dispose();
    cryRpt.Close();
}
```

I'll show you the snaps:
[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Morning friends. I modified my code in order to avoid asking parameters. I delete cryRpt.Dispose() and cryRpt.Close(). It works however I decided to put theses code lines in the winform closing event. My code is:

```
public FrmReport()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    rpDoc = new ReportDocument();
    crvReportes.AllowedExportFormats = (int)(ViewerExportFormats.ExcelFormat | ViewerExportFormats.PdfFormat| ViewerExportFormats.WordFormat);
}
private void LoadReport()
{
    try
    {
        rpDoc.Load((Application.StartupPath + "\\rpExclu.rpt").Replace("\\bin\\Debug", ""));
        rpDoc.SetParameterValue("@IDA", this.ida);
        rpDoc.SetDatabaseLogon(this.us, this.pass);
        crvReportes.ReportSource = rpDoc;
        crvReportes.Refresh();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        crvReportes.Refresh();
        XtraMessageBox.Show("" + ex.Message.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
private void FrmReporteBienes_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (rpDoc.IsLoaded)
    {
        rpDoc.Dispose();
        rpDoc.Close();
    }
}
```

Is it the best solution? Well in this moment It works. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to populate data from SQL, you can set up connection via rpt file, by choosing on your task bar *Database > Database Expert > OLE DB (ADO) (if MS SQL) > SQL Server Native Clinet*. Connection set up that way will be used also when report is evaluated,so you dont need to pass it every time.

Comment: Sure but the parameter? It's passed programatically.

Comment: Parameter need to be still pased via your backend, but with your credentials already hardcoded in *.rpt file, it should not ask for db credentials anymore.